# Remove "/SitePages/" or anything after the site name from url for SEO

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, seo

My SharePoint website developed on Office 365 online having the default home page redirects the url from (eg. `www.abc.com`) to (eg. `www.abc.com/SitePages/Home.aspx`).

I am looking for an option/solution for taking the `/SitePages/` from URL for SEO purpose so that the default home page redirects to the main url (eg. `www.abc.com`) , removing anything after the site name from url.

How can this be done?

Comment: I have a subsite and there are some sitepages. I want to have my URL xxx.com/subsite/page1 instead of xxx.com/subsite/sitepages/page1. IN reviewing your response above, there are no page folder under my subsite to move to. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got the answer. All you need to do is copy the `.aspx` page from `SitePages` into the `Pages` directory, set it as the Home Page through SP Designer. The extra folders and names will disappear :)

If you don't see the Pages directory, first enable the Publishing feature on the site.

Comment: There are no pages directory for me to move to under my subsite.

Comment: It is present in the "All Files" folder. You can access it via Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

site content > Pages > select page  in ribbon click on make homepage. 
any page you will select as make home page will be default home page for the site.
[image: image set as home page]